# Gitlab and JSON format

Tags: json, gitlab, gitlab-api

I have a problem with the API of Gitlab. I would like to export the issues of my project to a csv file. So before, i try to use the API and this command:

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: mytoken" https://mygitlab/projects/4/issues
```

My problem is the output is on html mode but i would like json format. I don't understand because in the api it's specified:

> The API uses JSON to serialize data. You don't need to specify .json
>   at the end of an API URL.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're trying to use is incorrect.

[the format is](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html): 
 `https://yourgitlab/api/v3/projects/4/issues`

So, basically you missed the `api/v3` part and you're not calling the api, but requesting an HTML page.

By the way, when I look at `projects/4/issues` I think that 4 is the value from an API sample. Make sure to use your project id instead.

Comment: If i add api/V3 it's better ^^. Thank you very much!